# How to delete selected row and update to DB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm working on some application and I want to add a button to delete a selected row in datagridview. The data in datagridview are imported from database.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: If you would like help then you have to give us something to help with. Questions of the form "I want to do this, tell me how" are off-topic here at SO. This is a place for questions of the form "I want to do this, here is how I am trying to do it, here's what happens when I try it, tell me how to fix it". If you don't have anything then you don't have anything to fix, so there's nothing for us to help with.

Comment: You might start out by seeing how to write a Delete statement in whatever dialect your database speaks. Usually you would reference the table's primary key in the where clause. Next look up the DataGridView and see how to remove a row.

Answer (score 0):

In vb.net you need to change your DataGridView settings to this:

```
    DGV.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    DGV.MultiSelect = False
```

Now you need to add a Button control and use this code:

```
    If DGV.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then

       Try

        ' SQL part: '

        Dim selectedRow = DGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString()

        connection.Open()

        Dim query as String = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE [columnname] = @selectedRow "

        Dim cmd as New SqlCommand(query, connection)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectedRow",selectedRow)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted !")

        connection.Close()

        ' DGV part: '

        Dim Row As Integer = DGV.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        DGV.Rows.RemoveAt(Row)

       Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
       End Try

    Else

        MsgBox("Select an element.")

    End If
```